# jqGrid - hide specific column or row in pivot

Tags: jqgrid, pivot, free-jqgrid

If we want to hide the column (month 7, range: border black)

or hide the column(year 2015, border green)

Is there any solution or jqGrid options that we can use it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jqPivot` method have no special options which allow you to hide some columns directly, but one can use `beforeInitGrid` callback to make any modifications of `colModel` **before** the grid will be created. The only problem is: one have to understand the exact name conversion for the columns used by `jqPivot` to write correct code of `beforeInitGrid` callback. So I describe some internals structures of `jqPivot` first of all and then the code of `beforeInitGrid` callback will be clear to understand. I explain the problem based on the example. I recommend all to read [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/jqPivot-in-version-4.9) too which provides additional information about `jqPivot` implemented in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.9.0.

First of all I have to remind that `jqPivot` get as input data which will be indexed based on `xDimension` and `yDimension` options and then one calculates aggregation function over all items with the same x and y values. The aggregation function will be specified by `aggregates` parameter. In other words `jqPivot` is "pre-processor" of input data. It analyses the data and generate new `data` and `colModel` which display more compact information about original data.

To implement your requirements one need to understand which column names will be used by `jqPivot` for the `colModel` which will be generated. Moreover one need understand how to get the corresponding `y` values for the column.

For example we have the following input data:

```js
var data = [{
        CategoryName: "Baby", ProductName: "Baby Oil",
        Price: "193.81", Quantity: "1",
        sellmonth: "7",  sellyear: "2011", week: "first"
    }, {
        CategoryName: "Mom",  ProductName: "Shampoo",
        Price: "93.81",  Quantity: "1",
        sellmonth: "12", sellyear: "2011", week: "first"
    }, {
        CategoryName: "none", ProductName: "beauty",
        Price: "93.81",  Quantity: "1",
        sellmonth: "12", sellyear: "2011", week: "second"
    }, {
        CategoryName: "none", ProductName: "beauty",
        Price: "93.81",  Quantity: "1",
        sellmonth: "12", sellyear: "2011", week: "third"
    }, {
        CategoryName: "none", ProductName: "Shampoo",
        Price: "105.37", Quantity: "2",
        sellmonth: "12", sellyear: "2011", week: "third"
    }, {
        CategoryName: "none", ProductName: "beauty",
        Price: "93.81",  Quantity: "1",
        sellmonth: "12", sellyear: "2015", week: "second"
    }];
```

and we use as jqPivot options

```js
$("#pvtCrewAttendance").jqGrid("jqPivot",
    data,
    {
        footerTotals: true,
        footerAggregator: "sum",
        totals: true,
        totalHeader: "Grand Total",
        totalText: "<span style='font-style: italic'>Grand {0} {1}</span>",
        xDimension: [
            { dataName: "CategoryName", label: "Category Name", sortorder: "desc" },
            { dataName: "ProductName", label: "Product Name", footerText: "Total:" }
        ],
        yDimension: [
            { dataName: "sellyear",  sorttype: "integer", totalHeader: "Total in {0}" },
            { dataName: "sellmonth", sorttype: "integer" }//,
            //{ dataName: "week" }
        ],
        aggregates: [
            { member: "Price",    aggregator: "sum", summaryType: "sum", label: "{1}" },
            { member: "Quantity", aggregator: "sum", summaryType: "sum", label: "{1}" }
        ]
    },
    {/* jqGrid options ...*/});
```

The resulting pivot grid will be displayed on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/pivotGroupingTotalsHideSomeColumns0.htm):

[image]

The above options means than qnique values of `CategoryName` and `ProductName` properties of input dat build `x`-values - the first rows of the grid. It's

```js
[["Baby", "Baby Oil"], ["Mom", "Shampoo"], ["none", "beauty"], ["none", "Shampoo"]]
```

The above array is `xIndex`. In the same way the unique `y`-values are

```js
[["2011", "7"], ["2011", "12"], ["2015", "12"]]
```

The values build the columns of `colModel`. If one use `totalHeader`, `totalHeader`, `totalText` or `totals: true` properties in some `yDimension` then additional columns with total sum over the group will be included. One uses `totalHeader` for `dataName: "sellyear"` in the above example. It means that additional two columns with both `aggregates` (sum by `Price` and sum by `Quantity`) will be inserted at the end of columns having `sellyear` "2011" and "2015".

The first names of columns of the grid will be `"x0"` and `"x1"` (corresponds the number of items in `xDimension`). Then there are columns which names starts with `y` and the ending `a0` and `a1` (corresponds the number of items in `aggregates`).  The final two "total" columns have the names `"ta0"` and `"ta1"` (corresponds the number of items in `aggregates`). If `aggregates` contains only from one element that the suffixes (ending) `a0` and `a1` will be missing in the column which starts with `y` or `t`. The grouping total columns have the names which starts with `y` have `t` in the middle and `a` at the end (like `y1t0a0`). I includes an example on column names from the example above

[image]

I hope that one will see the column names which I wrote in red color. It's the `name` values for all 14 columns: `x0`, `x1`, `y0a0`, `y0a1`, `y1a0`, `y1a1`, `y1t0a0`, `y1t0a1`, `y2a0`, `y2a1`, `y2t0a0`, `y2t0a1`, `ta0`, `ta1`.

Now it's important to mention that `jqPivot` includes `xIndex` and `yIndex` used for building of pivot table inside. To be exactly one can get `pivotOptions` parameter *of jqGrid* and examine `xIndex.items` and `yIndex.items` properties. One will see the arrays of items which I included above.

Finally one have now enough information to understand the below code used in [**the demo**](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/pivotGroupingTotalsHideSomeColumns.htm) which hides the columns which you asked:

[image]

The demo uses the following `beforeInitGrid` which hides the required columns:

```js
beforeInitGrid: function () {
    var $self = $(this), p = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam"),
        yItems = p.pivotOptions.yIndex.items, matches, iy, y,
        colModel = p.colModel, i, cm, l = colModel.length, cmName;

    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        cm = colModel[i];
        cmName = cm.name;
        if (cmName.charAt(0) === "y") { // x, y, t
            // aggregation column
            matches = /^([x|y])(\d+)(t(\d+))?(a)?(\d+)/.exec(cmName);
            if (matches !== null && matches.length > 1) {
                // matches[2] - iy - index if y item
                // matches[4] - undefined or total group index
                // matches[6] - ia - aggregation index
                iy = parseInt(matches[2], 10);
                y = yItems[iy];
                if (y != null && (y[0] === "2015" || (y[0] === "2011" && y[1] === "7"))) {
                    cm.hidden = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @mrjumpy: You are welcome! It's more easy to format the code and pictures on stackoverflow and I suppose that much more people will find the information of stackoverflow as in [issues of free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues)